# Copy c-string char by char to dynamic char*

Tags: c, c-strings

I have a `const char*` string, I want to copy that string character by character to dynamic `char*.

```
const char *constStr = "Hello world";
char *str = (char*) malloc(strlen(constStr)+1);
while(*constStr){
   *str = *constStr;
   constStr++;
   str++;
}
printf("%s", str);
free(str);
```

The problem is that previous code just copies each character of `constStr` to  only the first index of the `str`. I don't know why?

Comment: It copies the whole string, but, when you print it, you print only the end of the string! Because now `str` points to the end of the string. (actually it points just after the end)

Comment: cout << str << endl;  --- Where is str pointing here?

Comment: Is there a reason `strdup` or `strcpy` don't suit your needs?

Comment: @RetiredNinja: I want to copy the string character by character.

Comment: You aren't copying the string terminator, the `NUL` character.

Comment: Also, `str` is now at the end of the new string.

Comment: You also risk a SegFault for `free(str)` as `str` no longer points to the beginning of a block of memory returned by `malloc`. Recall your two responsibilities regarding dynamically allocating memory (1) always preserve a pointer to the beginning of the block returned by `malloc`, so (2) it can be freed when it is no longer required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the "classical" string copy solution:

```
const char *constStr = "Hello world";
char *str = malloc(strlen(constStr) + 1), *p = str;
/* Do not forget to check if str!=NULL !*/
while((*p++ = *constStr++));
puts(str);
```

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out, you are incrementing `str` pointer in each iteration, so you always end up printing the end of the string.

You can instead iterate over each character without incrementing the pointer. The following code worked for me:

```
const char *constStr = "Hello world";
int len = strlen(constStr);
char *str = (char *) malloc(len + 1);
int i;
for (i = 0; i <= len; ++i) {
    str[i] = constStr[i];
}
printf("%s", str);
free(str);
```

Comment: That doesn't null terminate the new string. If you're going to call `strlen` twice you may as well just save the length so you know where to terminate the new string.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Thanks! I updated my code based on your suggestions.

Comment: @pgngp: Thank you for your answer, your answer is correct too.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you didn't null terminate the string. That was the primary problem. To be more clear, it is not that you didn't nul terminate the string which is the problem but rather your use of them where a pointer to a nul terminated char array is expected is the problem. But even if you did there was significant amount of problems in the code.

You allocated the memory and the casted the return value of `malloc` which is unnecessary. `void*` to `char*` conversion is implicitly done.

malloc might not be able to service the request, it might return a null pointer. It is important to
check for this to prevent later attempts to dereference the null pointer.

Then you started copying - you copied everything except the NUL terminating character. And then you passed it to `printf`'s `%s` format specifier which expects a pointer to a null terminated char array. This is undefined behavior.

The one position, in the `str` is uninitialized - beware that accessing uninitialized value may lead to undefined behavior.

Also there is another problem, From standard §[7.22.3.3](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.22.3.3)

> The `free` function causes the space pointed to by `ptr` to be deallocated, that is, made available for further allocation. If `ptr` is a null pointer, no action occurs. *Otherwise, if the argument does not match a pointer earlier returned by a memory management function*, or if the space has been deallocated by a call to free or realloc, *the behavior is undefined*.

Yes so is is the case here? No. when you called `free(str)` `str` is not pointing to the dynamically allocated memory returned by the `malloc`. This is again undefined behavior.

The solution always is to keep a pointer which stores the address of the allocated chunk. The other answers already showed them (without repeating them - both of them provides a good solution).

You can use `strdup` or `strcpy` also - even if you don't need them now - get accustomed with them. It helps to know those. And yes `strdup` is not part of standard, it is a POSIX standard thing.

Example:

```
const char *constStr = "Hello world";
char *str = malloc(strlen(constStr)+1);
if( !str ){
    perror("malloc");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
char *sstr = str;
while(*constStr){
   *str = *constStr;
   constStr++;
   str++;
}
*str = 0;
printf("%s", sstr);
free(sstr);
```

Comment: Let me know if you don't understand any part of what I mentioned. I will try to be more clear.

Comment: Thank you for your effort and I appreciate that, but as you know the native language of most members here is not English so, the better thing is explaining the problem in short with a short example appears the right way.

Comment: @LionKing -- to each his own, but many of us prefer _complete_ answers to short incomplete answers. Posters often don't notice significant problems that don't appear to cause problems at first glance. Remember that the primary purpose of SO is not to answer your question for you, but to provide a searchable repository of accurate information. My only quibble with this answer is very minor: `strdup()` is POSIX, and widely available, but not Standard C.

Comment: @DavidBowling.: Yes ...added it. Thanks

Comment: @LionKing.: There are lots of things happening..how can it be short? I can post a short answer too...but that won't be explaining everything. That would help?

Comment: @coderredoc: I just talking about providing examples with the explanation.

Comment: @LionKing.: Oh..next time I get into machine I will do that.

Comment: @coderredoc: I thank you again,but if you have provided examples with your explanation, your answer would have been the best answer.

Comment: @LionKing.: I provided..you can use the code snippet in yours and it will work. Isn;t it?

Comment: @coderredoc: Unfortunately, you have provided an example after I have chosen the best answer. anyway, I appreciate your effort.

Comment: @LionKing.: Ah ofcourse..that's true. I don't mind. If it helped..I am glad. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> The problem is that previous code just copies each character of
>   constStr to only the first index of the str. I don't know why?

1. Use index variable.
2. Don't forget terminating '\0' because you have a good chance of segmentation fault.